# HttpWebRequest type "GET" returning error 400

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

It seems to be occurring only one machine and none of the other machines.

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://connect.zystemsgo.com/auto/");
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        SetCertificatePolicy();
        Application.DoEvents();
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I tried searching other 400 request errors, but it is not clear. How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Are you disposing of everything correctly (the code shown would imply not)?  How many simultaneous connections are you attempting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP Error 400](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) means Bad Request. This is being returned by the server.

Usually, when I'm debugging HTTP requests, I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the requests and responses and find out what's going on. It never fails.

Answer (score 1):

(Not really an answer, but too big for comment)

For what it's worth, I ran the following Python code (too lazy to spin up C# :), and it worked fine:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('connect.zystemsgo.com')
conn.request('GET', '/auto/')
resp = conn.getresponse()
data = resp.read()
print data           # expected ouput, just like visiting in a browser
print resp.status    # 200
```

Are you sure you are showing us the URL that is actually failing, or is your code a more general example?

Perhaps the server certificate is not installed on that machine? I wouldn't expect a HTTP 400 in that case, but it's the only thing I can think of so far...

Answer (score 0):

it is a bad request error .Are there no parameters in the request?
Can you post the response message,it will give some idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: I am just trying to download a file from the website. This is a bootstrap application which checks for the latest version of the file. What type of parameters are usually there in the request?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you advice me on how to form that request string?

Comment: I got some html as output when I ran your code minus the SetCertificatePolicy();
Application.DoEvents(); methods . The html has two links .Is that expected output? one of the links points to a directory,do you want to navigate to that? I was unable reproduce the 400 error.

Comment: I went to the direct web link of your request,i am guessing you want to download that msi installer in the directory .Am i correct?

Comment: Actually, I want to download the two .txt files and check their versions against the local ones and update it if necessary.

Comment: WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("Your complete url for the file", @"c:\myfile.txt");  This should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

The code that i supplied in the comment above works.
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
    webClient.DownloadFile("Your complete url for the file", @"c:\myfile.txt");

you need to have permission to write in the directory of your choice.

You could also try and use the async download if you want.I am not getting why it would not work on a certain machine.